# Too much space between letters in IntelliJ Idea Terminal

Tags: intellij-idea

How can i reduce the space between letters in the IntelliJ terminal? It shows too much space between the characters. The console shows the characters just fine, though.

---

**UPDATE**

Compare the IntelliJ console with the intelliJ terminal:

**Console**

[image]

**Terminal**

[image]

As you can see, I have a lot of space between the characters in the terminal, as compared to the console.

Comment: I think that attaching screenshots of both for comparison would be useful.

Comment: I just did @yeputons

Comment: I have never encountered that problem. I suggest you open an issue in JetBrains tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com and describe your setup as exactly as possible (OS version, IDEA version, Java version, Font Settings, ...)

Comment: It just happened to me when I updated to 2019.3.2 community edition. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Just happened to me as well when updating to 2021.1 any solutions yet?

Comment: yup, found this after uibuntu Snap automatically updated to 2021.1 on ubuntu

Comment: Same problem for my IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1 (Ultimate Edition), when switching between light and dark themes. It does appear on PyCharm 2022.2 (Professional Edition)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set a different console font from the settings.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me also on all of my log and terminal consoles when I updated to 2021.1 yesterday. It turned out that my console font had been set to an obscure font I had not seen before. I reset the console font to the default (Fira 16) and the problem was fixed.

IntelliJ was searching for settings during the upgrade, so maybe this was where the problem started.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue happen to me recently.

I changed the bundled JRE that comes with the Intellij Idea. Here's how you can change the JRE.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to change to a monospaced font, and close all tabs. There should be no space between letters anymore after you restart the software.

Comment: Shouldn‘t it also work with proportional font?